# How much proteins during rest day?

Tags: protein, food, rest

Assume you your weight is 75 kg (standard).
You practised 5 days in a row by the schedule

Each day 1.5 h

- 2 x 15 min (cardio)
- 1h long movement trainings, series practise

  - 3x15 for pushups,
  - pull-ups,
  - pull-downs/ups, mostly

You eat

- breakfast (15 proteins)
- lunch (10-20 proteins)
- midday (10-20 proteins)

I think 55 gram of proteins (about 0.73 g/kg is not enough proteins) during rest because at least I feel weak with only 55 gram of proteins.
For me, I think adding a few eggs (30 g) and/or some whey protein (30g) can help.

I read that body builders should eat like 2.5 gram of proteins per kilogram.
I am interested how much this should be during rest days.

If the body builder have allergies, I think the intake of proteins should be little higher.
However, I cannot confirm this hypothesis.

**How much proteins is good during rest days?**

Comment: How much calories are you putting in? Are you experiencing fatigue with this diet? This seems like a low protein intake. Average is around .75 to 1 gram per pound. What's your ratio?

Comment: @IvanIvković - I think you mean .75 to 1g per kilogram, not pound. For the OP, 1-2 g/kg should be plenty as a daily intake. 2.5 g/kg is overkill, it likely won't do any harm but you probably aren't getting anything more out of the extra intake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't eat less protein on rest days. The muscles get damaged during workout, but they get *repaired* during rest, so you need the protein for that, as well as for building new muscle.

That said 1g per pound of lean body mass would be good if you want to keep all your muscle. With 75kg and a presumed 15% bodyfat you'd have ~64kg (141lbs) of lean body mass. So you'd eat  around 141g of protein a day, which is much more than in your example. Many bodybuilders eat 200g or more just to be safe, although the need to do it is heavily debated.

I was actually quite taken aback by that example btw. How would you do that, if you're not on a hardcore diet? With 75kg you'd eat at least 2000 kcal for maintenance with 55g protein only making up 220kcal (11%), that's much too low, and not just for athletes.

Also let's talk about some myths that *will* always come up when someone suggests higher protein intake:

- if you consume more protein than you need, it *does not* turn into fat automatically. Too much calories and too little exercise make you fat, not a high protein intake.
- Kidney failure will *not* happen with a high protein diet, if your drink enough (2-3 liters a day, minimum).
- a high protein diet is not more likely to cause cancer (as suggested by that study some weeks ago).

Keep in mind that I have a strength-training/bodybuilding background and this could be vastly inaccurate for endurance sports, which depend on a higher carb intake.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is really useful in combining the knowledge of water intake with high protein diet. I have to drink whey proteins to get enough proteins daily because I do not have so many breaks to eat besides school.

Comment: No problem. If you fell this answers your question fully you should accept it, so others see that this question is done.